How to use "import" syntax to import js file
I created a node/webpack project to display two html pages, the index.js file can import jquery package correctly, but in another html page which is opened by the first index page, the jquery package can't be imported directly. Can someone give any suggestions here? Thanks
The project structure:

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Getting Started</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <button onclick="openNewPage()">This is a test page...</button>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
              console.log('this is main page...')
          });


          function openNewPage() {
              console.log('open ...')
              window.open('another.html')
          }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>

index.js
import _ from 'lodash';

import jquery from 'jquery';
var $ = require("jquery");
window.$ = $;


function component() {
  const element = document.createElement('div');

  // Lodash, now imported by this script
  element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');

  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());

another.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Another Page...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>Hi, I am another page...</div>
      <script type="module" src="another.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
              console.log('this is another page...')
          });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>

another.js
import jquery from 'jquery';
var $ = require("jquery");
window.$ = $;

import setting from '../setting.js'

package.json
{
  "name": "getting-started-using-a-configuration",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "serve dist"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "serve": "^12.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.38.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"
  }
}

webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};

The error information is below:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at another:11:11
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "jquery". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

The project url in stackblitz:
the two html page example project in stackblitz

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Thanks, I have removed the error image
